# Is this restricted promise-3SAT version coNPComplete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Given a $3SAT$ problem the decision version of the problem (if it has a solution or not) is $NPComplete$. Now, given that we consider the promise version of the $3SAT$ problem, the promise is every $3SAT$ problem provided always has at least 1 solution.

**Query**: Does every solution of the above $3SAT$ problem instance have a particular property (one that can be tested in polynomial time. For eg: 'for any solution $A_i$, $N$ numbers immediately smaller than A are co-prime' or something similar; where $N$ is the input length)?

The problem and property can be encoded as a pair consisting of $3SAT$, and another $N$ input circuit of polynomial size ($N^c$ for some constant $c$)

This promise version is definitely in $co-NP$ (as if there is a solution that does not satisfy the given property, that solution is the $co-NP$ certifcate of polynomial length).

Is this problem also $co-NPComplete$ (as it still involves getting the failing solution first)?

Comment: Can you formulate your problem precisely? How do you encode the property?

Comment: If we have an Algorithm that tests the given property, the running time of the Algorithm on a DTM would be polynomial/bounded w.r.t. to the bits in the input size. Thus, I was assuming we can always have a polynomial sized circuit that tests the same. (I assumed that was the query regarding encoding)

Comment: How does an instance of your problem look? A pair consisting of a CNF on $n$ variables and a circuit on $n$ inputs? Note that "polynomial size" circuit doesn't quite make sense - you need to fix the polynomial. For every polynomial you can have a different variant of your problem. Alternatively, the circuit can be unrestricted - the problem only becomes easier.

Comment: Given a CNF and a solution, it is NP-complete to ask whether there is another solution (if I remember correctly). This involves a reduction which plants a specific solution. If your property is "all solutions are the planted solution", then you get a coNP-complete problem.

Comment: The problem would be the same as you described. A pair consisting of 3CNF, and another N input circuit of polynomial size (the algorithm has a DTM has a running time of N^c, where c is some constant, so yes the polynomial constant is fixed). I am aware of the problem - I think its called 'Another SAT' but not about the 'planting approach' (have to look it up). The form of the property can be something like: 'for any solution A, N numbers immediately smaller than A are co-prime or something similar'.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your post with a formal statement of your problem.

Comment: You asked if it is NP-complete.  What have you tried?  Try to formalize your problem, then try to find a reduction partner (another NP-complete problem) and reduce from the partner to your problem.  What reduction partners have you tried so far?  What reduction strategies have you tried so far?  If you don't have anything you can talk about that you've tried so far, it might make more sense to spend more time on the problem before asking here.

Comment: thanks. The thing is that was and still is a theoretical question, not a specific  instance of the 'property'. There is no single particular instance (the one mentioned in the brackets is off hand and perhaps might not even be the best, I posted it to clarify what i meant a property could look like) so I cannot attempt a reduction. Sadly, It is more conceptual/generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is coNP-complete when the property is "all variables are zero". Given a SAT formula $\varphi$ on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, construct a new SAT formula $\psi$ by replacing each clause $C$ of $\varphi$ with $\lnot y \lor C$ (where $y$ is a new variable), and adding clauses $y \lor \lnot x_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. The satisfying assignments of $\psi$ are obtained from those of $\psi$ by setting $y = 1$, and there is an additional satisfying assignment in which all variables are zero. Hence $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff not all satisfying assignments of $\psi$ satisfy the property.